# 10k Deleted List not showing full range

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

The `Recent Occurrences:Recently Deleted` list in the 10k tools won't show all the posts in the chosen date range.  It appears to limit out at 45 posts (with no pagination).

Comment: 10K tools is woefully inadequate.