# Please show us when one of our posts gets deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Now that we are notified when we [lose an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/please-show-us-when-we-lose-an-accepted-answer/107007#107007), can we go a step further and be notified when one of our posts (question or answer) gets deleted by someone other than ourselves?

This will take care of the last "vanishing reputation" problem. I've been losing quite a bit of rep (I do re-calcs every week or so) and it's got to be from deletions.... It would be nice if we knew what they were.

EDIT: I did I recalc yesterday... And my rep is already out of sync again. The audit says I have 34 points less than my on-site rep.

Comment: I'm not sure how constructive being notified of "your post was deleted because it's Viagra spam/horribly offensive" would be. Maybe an exception there.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Maybe only notify if the user loses rep

Comment: You lose up to 100 rep from spam/offensive-deleted posts.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yes, but you get notified of that on the rep audit.

Comment: Do you? I didn't know that.

Comment: I think the real answer is [Can we get a list of our content that's been deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/can-we-get-a-list-of-our-content-thats-been-deleted) since it would allow you to see what's been deleted for any purpose, not just for the purpose of explaining reputation changes.

Comment: I don't see this ever being implemented *unless* the request @agf links to is implemented. Even then, it's kinda asking for a feature that automatically rubs in the salt whenever you get cut.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think so... It actually befuddles me to check the rep audit and see rep disappear for no reason. I would be nice to know how that happened.

Comment: But... You already know how it happened. Or you wouldn't be asking for this!

Comment: @Shog9 Not how, but where

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes

Comment: Ironically, [agf's link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107017/please-show-us-when-one-of-our-posts-gets-deleted?rq=1#comment275141_107017) points to a deleted question. It should probably point to [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/)

Answer (score 14):

This would also help find old deleted posts, since they don't show in your list in the profile, and the deleted list [was broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92979/restore-the-10k-ability-to-see-all-closed-deleted-posts-in-a-list) and [never fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94442/10k-deleted-list-not-showing-full-range) in the 10k tools.