# Missing question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I flagged up one of my questions asking if it could be changed to a wiki post and now it no longer shows up on my profile, just wondering if it got deleted or if this is meant to happen when they get changed to community wiki posts?

Edit:-
Now that I know what happened to my question I've started a new question in the hopes of finding out why it happened as my comment questions here haven't been fruitful in that area
[Question about why.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107424/why-my-question-was-deleted-after-being-made-a-wiki)

Comment: Can you give us a link to the question in question?

Comment: Or at least a clue to it's title

Comment: thats the problem I can't find it and I don't remember it's title as I made it months and month ago.

Comment: The site it was on would also help. Tags. Topic. Anything else you know, really.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well I was meaning it was on this site and it was a feature request which was to do with the option of being able to hide profile questions/answers on profile page, I've searched for it and can't find it and was mainly making this topic with the hopes an admin would read it since I know even if a question gets deleted they can still see it as far as I'm aware and possibly could track what happened to it via my flag logs.

Comment: the irony of losing a question from my profile page when that's what the question was sort of about

Answer (score 4):

Argh, I wrote a four-paragraph analysis of how this was a bug... and then I found the question. Here it is: [Make displaying previous questions/answers on your own profile page optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74235/make-displaying-previous-questions-answers-on-your-own-profile-page-optional). Deleted by Jeff two days ago. If it makes you feel better, someone *did* convert it to CW before the deletion happened.

Comment: It would of been either yesterday or on tuesday when I flagged it asking it to be made a community wiki, it was on meta not SO and it has been a question for months so it's not offensive although it did get a lot of debate started.

Comment: if I check all my folders I might get lucky and find a copy of it which if nobody can find out what happened to my previous question then I guess I'll just have to repost it.

Comment: @Myzifer please refresh the page to see my edit. I found your question several minutes ago.

Comment: @Myzifer - Not to be harsh here, but if something was deleted, it was likely for good reason...I'd recommend against re-posting it.

Comment: refreshed, any idea why it was deleted (or how I can find out?) and why I wasn't informed over any of the steps taken?

Comment: @NickCraver It's been up for months and I wasn't informed about anything or even given the chance to appeal the decision, not to mention I brought up reposting because I requested it be made a community wiki then poof it vanishes so as the question indicated I wasn't aware what had been done.

Comment: It sounds like you'll be interested in [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107017/please-show-us-when-one-of-our-posts-gets-deleted), @Myzifer.

Comment: @PopularDemand I am and just upvoted it now that you pointed it out, kinda surprised it's not already a feature as it will otherwise just generate even more unneeded questions be made just to find out a question was 1-deleted 2-why it was deleted.

Comment: The link in this post has now been deleted so it is not possible to assess whether the moderator decision was fair or not.

Answer (score 4):

See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

> Questions that are [extremely off topic](/faq#dontask), or of very low quality,
>   may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions
>   may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over
>   a very long period after being asked. For additional guidance, see  [How to Ask](/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: The only area that sits into this is that it has had no recent activity but I still think it provided a useful signpoint for any future questions on the matter.

I also disagree with my deletion question being a duplicate as this question was clearly to find out what had happened to my question, where as my deletion question was focused on why they had occured.

I know that a fair few people disagreed with my original question about profile page data but I still think it's a valid discussion which would prove useful in the future should and when it occurs to someone else.

Comment: I still don't know why exactly my question was deleted and would like to appeal that decision.