# Why my question was deleted after being made a wiki?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107193/missing-question)

[Question link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74235/make-displaying-previous-questions-answers-on-your-own-profile-page-optional)

I enquired as to what happened to it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107193/missing-question/107198#107198) just to be told it had been made into a wiki and then deleted, ofc no reason given to me why it was deleted so it's left me wondering if they didn't think it was an appropriate wiki then instead of deleting it then it shouldn't of been converted.

So back to the reason I created this question, why was my other question deleted?

Comment: @PaddedCell This is clearly not a duplicate as the 1st question was me asking if wiki question vanish from user profile page because I didn't know what had happened to it then, now I do and as such I have made a very precise question asking why it was deleted which is very different!

Comment: Jeff Atwood already replied on the other question about why the question was deleted. His answer implies the question you were querying about was deleted, and gives the reasons why a question is deleted.

Comment: @kiamlaluno his reply was a merge from this topic so no by the creation of this topic he hadn't replied and this question is still valid dispite being voted otherwise as the "Missing Question" topic was about trying to find out were my question had gone hence the missing part where as this question was made to find out exactly why it was deleted which I still have yet to receive anything more than a generic answer which could mean many things, 1 of being whether it would be a useful signpoint which I think it would as it's a question covering a major component of SO.

Answer (score 1):

See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

> Questions that are [extremely off topic](/faq#dontask), or of very low quality,
>   may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions
>   may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over
>   a very long period after being asked. For additional guidance, see  [How to Ask](/questions/how-to-ask).