# Duplicate asking to explain chunk of code, with more than 400 upvotes, was deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

My [question about a block of JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10), "Can you explain why ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] = 10", was deleted and I want to know why.

It is a programming question with 400+ upvotes that contains a fantastic answer.

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: This is why the whole deletionism thing without having a proper archive is seriously broken. Unless somebody happens to notice, deleted stuff will simply be gone forever. There is no proper way to get the good stuff back. No recent deletions list, no nothing. But Stack Exchange, Inc. doesn't give a damn, and this battle is lost.

Comment: Wonder why the accepted answer says "deleted by owner" when they weren't one of the delete voters at all.

Comment: There is a recently deleted list http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days @pek

Comment: @random thanks, I just discovered that

Comment: @random It currently shows up in the "recent undelete" votes. But it is long buried in the "recently deleted". All the hundreds of non-answers also go into the "recently deleted" list which has only a limited # of spots.

Comment: its undeleted now.

Comment: Such a high quality answer should have been merged with the identified duplicate, rather than deleted, IMHO.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Well, it's not "exact"-enough to be mergeable.

Comment: @Pekka, be aware that the recently deleted list has a hard limit that at last count was 30, I wrote an [FR on it a few years back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94442/10k-deleted-list-not-showing-full-range).

Comment: Undeleted with 10 votes. Thanks for posting this, @John!

Comment: @downvoters care to comment?

Comment: @random why did you removed my edit?

Comment: That was commentary, because at this rate you'll be editing it every time it bobs up and down the riverbank

Comment: @pekka you should know more than anyone that it's not lost.  And if anyone doesn't notice, does it matter? I'd argue no.  And if someone *does* notice it, like in this case, it goes through the wash-rinse-repeat cycle as it has here.  If it was a hard delete then I could empathize more with your statement but the lack of hard deletes + lack of care + cyclical nature of these things just means the machine keeps on turning.  An archive would be nice but I don't think all is as lost or has the potential to be lost as one might interpret from your comment.

Comment: @casper somebody with 10k rights, or the owner, needs to notice. For anyone else, the page is simply gone. Of course it still exists somewhere, but what does that matter when the majority of people can't see it and no one is informed of it? And re noticing - it took *months* and some coincidences for me to notice some of my own deleted questions which had content worth preserving. I might never have - why should I check out questions whose answers I already know by heart? To me, the deletion process is broken, period. (And I'm saying that as a mostly deletionist, and a close-ist)

Comment: @Pekka I think that's where we disagree.  *Needs* to notice?  I don't agree with that assessment.  Also, it doesn't take the owner or 10K rights to notice.  Simply going to the URL and getting a 404 is enough to notice.  Which leads back to the question "if no one notices..." and entry into the cycle.

Comment: @casper so, what does the non-10k user do once they've noticed the question is gone? Suppose they don't know they can request undeletion on Meta, maybe even don't know about Meta *at all*, which I'm sure is the case for the majority of people. A non-10k user knows literally *nothing* about why the question was deleted.

Comment: @Pekka That's a separate issue.  That question is a general "does the low-rep user know enough about meta" and in my eyes, a larger issue that is beyond the scope of this particular topic.

Comment: @casper it indeed is a larger issue and has nothing to do with the topic at hand. Low-rep users will likely neverknow enough about Meta. Which is why saying "hey, if you want a deleted question back, you can always start a Meta question" is a complete joke. A non-10k user currently has no obvious way to understand why a question was gone, and what they can do about it. That is a completely broken state of affairs on a supposedly community-run site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> deleted by Jonas, artbristol, BalusC, John Saunders, bmargulies, ACB,
>   Andro Selva, NullPointer, Abhijit, tchrist Jan 13 at 2:21

In my opinion, that question should not have been deleted. And as such, I actually cast (either the 1st or 2nd) undelete vote on it when I discovered it about a week ago.

1. It is a <strike>high</strike> decent quality question.
2. It has a very high quality answer.

Joel himself even spoke out against deleting duplicates.

---

EDIT:

> Post Undeleted by Mysticial, sehe, NullPointer, Martin Smith, Graham
>   Borland, Kyle Trauberman, Shawn Chin, bfavaretto, ire_and_curses,
>   ThiefMaster♦

10 users voted to undelete. So it is back now.

Comment: It's a terrible question. This is about as far from practical as you can get. Every time I see one of these "*what/why happens if you mash a bunch of operators together nonsensically*" questions I vote to close[.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990/why-does-i-j-k-j-i-kk-i-j-11) I wouldn't mind a historical lock, but this definitely doesn't deserve to be open.

Comment: @Jeremy he's not advocating reopening though, just undeletion

Comment: @Pekka I don't disagree with that. I was reacting (over-reacting?) to the remark that "it is a high quality question".

Comment: @JeremyBanks Maybe it's not the best of questions, but it certainly isn't as bad as these: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105365/stack-overflow-has-too-many-too-localised-new-questions

Comment: When questions get deleted, the same names always pop up. Incredible.

Comment: Why is that incredible, @NullUserException? People have different opinions, why should those change?

Comment: Interesting NullPointer voted to delete and undelete...

Comment: @Arjan Because we have over 3300 users with deletion powers, but I bet less than 1% of them are responsible for more than 99% of all deletions. Essentially we have a band of exclusionists who wreak havoc on the site deleting useful questions. I've said this already, but they shouldn't have removed the popularity requirement. A question like this would've required hundreds of delete votes and we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I don't know if moderators have access to a list of popular deleted questions. But it might be worthwhile for a mod to make a meta post with a list of them and ask the community to vote on the ones that should come back. Normal users can't search for deleted content.

Comment: @NullUserException, I didn't know they had removed the popularity requirement.

Comment: @Mysticial, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-meta-questions-archive) and the link in that question for more.

Comment: @LanceRoberts They did. Now it only takes 10 delete votes. And once they start to pile on, the question is as good as deleted. We went from a system that worked just fine, to this crap.

Comment: TBH, I strongly suspect that there's some jealousy with many of the "lucky" popular questions. If this question had only 10 votes, people wouldn't be so frantic to delete it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I disagree with your assertion that it's a terrible question. It's a really good question that requires deep knowledge of how JavaScript's type conversions and operator precedence all work. That's like saying it's useless to calculate 10 trillion digits of PI or send a man to the moon. It isn't, even if some people are too myopic to realize that know-how gained from accomplishing one task can have practical applications elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It has been stated before that questions with good answers shouldn't be deleted, we certainly wouldn't want to lose [Bobince's classic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/13295).

Comment: That is a classic, and it is funny, but not particularly informative. Contrast it with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/825789